# Specific accordeon-menu behavior, possibly jquery ui or bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create an accordeon-navigation with a specific behavior: The first of the collapsible contents does not have a toggle-link but instead will be shown on start of the site AND when the following (so the second) collapsible content is closed.

I tried before to achieve this with both bootstraps collapse-feature and the jqueryi-ui-accordeon, but never really got it to work the way I described. So I built it manually just with jquery, but now I can't really get the "slide and push" effect, which basically is the "heart" of accordeon elements I think to work.

You can see it basically running in this fiddle with a not-so-beautiful fade effect: 
http://jsfiddle.net/8fL6L/31/

```
    Sry, I have to add fake code here, otherwise I can't post the fiddle-link...
```

When I use jquery-ui's slide-effect instead of fading, the content to slide up just slides out but does not push/pull the content above/below it with it.
So, does anyone have an idea how to achieve this - either with the bootstrap or jquery-ui accordeon or by modifying my code?

Much thanks for thinking about it in advance! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry folks, came up with my own solution, posting it here now in case it helps anyone in the future.

I slightly modified bootstrap's collapse()-functionality so that on closing one collapsible, the previous collapsible is automatically opened (if it exists). That's the only "new" thing, the opening of one collapsible by default was already easily possible without modifying anything in bootstrap.

http://jsfiddle.net/8fL6L/51/

Just give the wrapping container of the collapsibles the id

```
    #collapsibles
```

, call

```
    initCollapsibles()
```

on $(document).ready() and you're good to go.

Hope, this might some day help someone. :-)